# Show C# reference documentation in intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

If I create a List list.. Visual Studio offers its members with intellisense, but there is no documentation for the members. If I go to the definition of List, I see the following:

```
[DefaultMember("Item")]
public class List<T> : IEnumerable, ICollection, IList, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList<T>
{
    // ...
    public void Add(T item);
    public void Clear();
    public bool Contains(T item);
    // ...
}
```

There is no comments/descriptions for any of the members. This applies to any other core classes.

What can I do to make Visual Studio 2017 show the documentation so I don't have to Alt+Tab to the official C# reference documentation website any time I want to know what a method does?

Is there any SDK library I have to add in order to have documentation?

I'm using Visual Studio on Unity projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this but you have to know two things

**1.Where Unity's framework dll are located**:

When "Scripting Runtime Version" is set to ".NET 3.5 Equivalent" in the Editor, the C# DLL API used is at:

```
<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\unity
```

When "Scripting Runtime Version" is set to ".NET 4.x Equivalent" in the Editor, the latest framework is used the path ends with the framework version:

```
<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\<API-version>
```

*This path may change in the future.* To find the current path to the dll Unity is using, simply expand the Assembly and References in the *"Solution Explorer"* tab in Visual Studio then select one of the C# DLL. In the example below, **System.dll** is selected, the path will be displayed under the property.

[image]

---

---

**2.Where the C# standard framework dll are located**:

When using ".NET 3.5 Equivalent" in the Unity Editor, the corresponding C# framework API used is at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Client
```

When using ".NET 4.x Equivalent" in the Unity Editor, the corresponding C# framework API used is at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\<API-version>
```

---

**Showing C# core documentation  in Visual Studio**:

Now that you know the locations, notice that each dll in the *standard framework location* from **#2** has a complimentary xml file that ends with `.xml` extension. For example, the `System.Core.dll` dll, has complementary file named `System.Core.xml` in the-same folder. Each `xml` file contains the documentation for each corresponding dll file.

All you have to do is copy `xml` file for each `dll` file from the *standard framework location* into *Unity's framework dll* location. Restart Visual Studio and documentation  should be working.

This is time consuming to do manually so I made an Editor plugin to handle it. Enable it by going to the *Programmer*-->*Enable Core Documentation* menu and disable it by going to the *Programmer*-->*Disable Core Documentation* menu. You must restart Visual Studio in order for this to take effect.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class DocEnabler : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Replace both with the proper paths on your system
    static string unityFrameworkPath = @"G:\Applications\Unity\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\unity";
    static string stdCoreFrameworkPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Client";

    [MenuItem("Programmer/Enable Core Documentation")]
    static void EnableCoreDoc()
    {
        CopyFilesByExt(stdCoreFrameworkPath, unityFrameworkPath, "xml");
    }

    [MenuItem("Programmer/Disable Core Documentation")]
    static void DisableCoreDoc()
    {
        DeleteFilesByExt(unityFrameworkPath, "xml");
    }

    static void DeleteFilesByExt(string path, string ext)
    {
        DirectoryInfo drctyInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] files = drctyInfo.GetFiles("*." + ext)
                             .Where(p => p.Extension == "." + ext).ToArray();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
                file.Delete();
                //File.Delete(file.FullName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log("Error while deleting file: " + file.Name + "\r\n" + e.Message);
            }
        }
        DoneMessage();
    }

    static void CopyFilesByExt(string source, string destPath, string ext)
    {
        DirectoryInfo drctyInfo = new DirectoryInfo(source);
        FileInfo[] files = drctyInfo.GetFiles("*." + ext)
                             .Where(p => p.Extension == "." + ext).ToArray();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                string fromPath = file.FullName;
                string toPath = Path.Combine(destPath, file.Name);

                file.CopyTo(toPath, true);
                //File.Copy(fromPath, toPath, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log("Error while Copying file: " + file.Name + "\r\n" + e.Message);
            }
        }
        DoneMessage();
    }

    static void DoneMessage()
    {
        Debug.Log("Action complete. Restart Visual Studio for the changes to take effect");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Coming to this in 2021.  Programmer's solution still works, but the locations have changed and there is another copy that needs to happen to support netstandard 2.0.

I hope Programmer doesn't mind but I adjusted the script with the changed default locations and added the netstandard 2.0 locations.  JetBrains Rider has the same problem and solution.

My experience in this field is 2 days strong, so use with caution.  But it solved all of my problems.

**EDIT:** I discovered that not only can these dir names vary among systems, but Windows doesn't ship with the netstandard reference by default.  I'll correct this post when I find where it came from.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class DocEnabler : MonoBehaviour
{
  //Replace both with the proper paths on your system

  // .NET 4.x
  static string unityFrameworkPath = @"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.5f1\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.7.1-api";
  static string microsoftFrameworkPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.X";

  // .NETSTANDARD 2.0
  static string unityNetStandardPath = @"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.5f1\Editor\Data\NetStandard\ref\2.0.0";
  static string microsoftNetStandardPath = @"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\NETStandard.Library.Ref\2.1.0\ref\netstandard2.1";

  [MenuItem("Programmer/Enable Core Documentation")]
  static void EnableCoreDoc()
  {
    CopyFilesByExt(microsoftFrameworkPath, unityFrameworkPath, "xml");
    CopyFilesByExt(microsoftNetStandardPath, unityNetStandardPath, "xml");
  }

  [MenuItem("Programmer/Disable Core Documentation")]
  static void DisableCoreDoc()
  {
    DeleteFilesByExt(unityFrameworkPath, "xml");
    DeleteFilesByExt(unityNetStandardPath, "xml");
  }

  static void DeleteFilesByExt(string path, string ext)
  {
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles("*." + ext)
      .Where(p => p.Extension == "." + ext).ToArray();

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
      try
      {
        file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
        file.Delete();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Debug.Log("Error while deleting file: " + file.Name + "\r\n" + e.Message);
      }
    }
    DoneMessage();
  }

  static void CopyFilesByExt(string source, string destPath, string ext)
  {
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(source);
    FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles("*." + ext)
      .Where(p => p.Extension == "." + ext).ToArray();

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
      try
      {
        string toPath = Path.Combine(destPath, file.Name);
        file.CopyTo(toPath, true);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Debug.Log("Error while Copying file: " + file.Name + "\r\n" + e.Message);
      }
    }
    DoneMessage();
  }

  static void DoneMessage()
  {
    Debug.Log("Action complete. Restart Visual Studio for the changes to take effect");
  }
}
```

I would've posted as a comment and included some proof images, but I don't have enough karma yet.

[Here's a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OptSv.png) to an image of it working on a `.NET 2.0` project in Visual Studio.

Comment: I can confirm this works for .netstandard 2.1 in 2022 version.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in the Unity Answers site [Here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1409129/why-does-visual-studio-not-show-tooltip-intellisen.html).

> Answer by Blue_Ninja0 · Sep 21, 2017 at 09:41 PM
>
> It has been brought to my attention that Unity doesn't include the System.xml file required for Intellisense documentation for their old mono runtime.
>
> It seems from Unity 2017 onwards, as long as you enable .NET 4.6 on the API Compatibility Level setting on the Player Settings, you will get full documentation. I have tested and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had to stick to version 3.5 so I had to choose another solution.

Comment: This did not work for me in 2022.